# AccessDeniedException; Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using the Spring Security default login page and if my user get to a page that he should not be getting to based on role and url he gets the following error on the screen:

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied to login

How can I make it some Spring goes to the default login with or without a error.  please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the `<access-denied-handler>` element in the documentation's [Appendix B](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-access-denied-handler), you can set the `errorPage` attribute to forward to a custom JSP. This could be your login page or whatever else you want. Keep in mind that at this point, the user is already logged in, so forwarding them to the login page (again) may be confusing.

As Raghuram suggested, you can also implement `AccessDeniedHandler` yourself, but I'd hold off on doing that unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the info in front of me, but if I remember correctly when you setup spring security you can give it url patterns to apply the security to. It sounds like your setup is including the login page in the patterns that security is applying to. You need to make sure that it is not. Go back to the spring security doco and you should be able to work this out. Also the spring logs are usually very good at helping with this sort of thing.

Comment: no i did not put the login page in thats why i would think it would goto the spring login page but its not

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is to override the default AccessDeniedHandlerImpl as documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#access-denied-handler).