# jsf spring security acces denied authentication login

Tags: jsf, authentication, spring-security, access-denied

I use Spring Security 3 in my jsf2 web app.

When a non-authenticated user tries to access a protected resource, Spring Security redirects to the login page.

In this case, how can I show a message to the user in the login page saying he/she is not allowed to access the resource?

As Spring Security throws an AccessDeniedException in the ExceptionTranslationFilter, and then redirects to the login page, I've tried to use a preRenderView listener in the login page, which checks for "WebAttributes.ACCESS_DENIED_403", but it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get you, actually if the user is not yet authenticated then an AuthenticationException is thrown and ExceptionTranslationFilter will launch the authenticationEntryPoint. So just add error request parameter like this.

```
<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
 class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
 <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
 class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
 <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.xhtml?error=true"/>
</bean>

and in your login.xhtml use the param like this

<h:outputText rendered="#{param['error']}" value="Please authenticate first!" />
```

Comment: The Spring Security tag library is for rendering components depending on if an authenticated user has a certain/s role/s, that is, it deals with authorization. But my case does nothing to do with authorization, but authentication. Even more, in my app I don't have roles for users. I just want to show a message in the login page when a non authenticated user is redirected to it because he tried to access a page for which authentication is required.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi. Finally I've found that this is the right solution. It works. I append the ?error=true to the loginFormUrl, and then I check for it in a preRenderView listener in the login page, in order to show a meesage to the user.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a duplicate question mentioned here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494103/accessdeniedexception-spring-security)

As mentioned create an instance AccessDeniedHandlerImpl and set its property to your custom error page. From that page use simple javascript to forward to the actual login page like

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.setTimeout('window.location="http://localhost:8080/WebApp/login.xhtml"; ',5000);
 </script>
```

or just provide a button or link to the login page.

Comment: My scenario is not that. My case is that the user isn't authenticated yet, and that's why he's sent to the login page. It's not the access denied page that a user is sent when he is authenticated but he hasn't the allowed role.

Comment: If the user is not yet authenticated, spring security will always send the user to the login page and after authentication if the user does not have access to the requested resource then an access denied page is displayed. I am assuming you do not want the default access denied page sent by the web application server. For that see below

Comment: I know that a non authenticated user is redirected to the login page. What I want is to show a mesage to the user in that login page. That's what I asked in my question

Answer (score 0):

add this to your web.xml

```
    <error-page>
       <error-code>403</error-code>
       <location>/pages/errorAccessDenied.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

and then create a errorAccessDenied.xhtml with your message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
     <h:outputText value="You do not have access to the requested resource" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: and if you have header links to other resources, the user can easily navigate to other pages that he is allowed to.